# Enums in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, enums, indexing

I want to store enum values in MongoDB collection. Can I effectively store them as strings? Will it affect index performance in comparison with enum values as ints? Does Mongo indexer optimize string indexes in the case when they contain only few fixed options as string values, to achieve speed similar to querying index by sorted integer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store enum MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393582/store-enum-mongodb)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Storing enum values in MongoDB as strings is perfectly fine, and yes, if you index the field I'd expect the performance to be comparable to indexed integer queries.  It's certainly more expressive than using integers.

The only real downside is that they'll take more space if your enum strings are somewhat long, but that's a pretty trivial concern.

Comment: Has anyone ever done any performance measurements related to this? Comparing strings is slower than comparing integers. This might affect querying as well as insertion and index (re)building, although the index does significantly reduce the number of comparisons needed. Never make any claims about performance without benchmarks.