# What is the best way to store constant strings in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my nodejs app I have collection - `football_players`. Docs in this collection have information about role of the player. For example:

```
[
  {
    id: 'some_id_1',
    name: 'Player1',
    role: 'FORWARD',
  },
  {
    id: 'some_id_2',
    name: 'Player2',
    role: 'DEFENDER',
  },
  {
    id: 'some_id_3',
    name: 'Player3',
    role: 'FORWARD',
  },
]
```

All types of role are constants. What is the best way to store it in MongoDB:

1. as strings (like in my example)
2. make declaration:

   `const roles = { FORWARD: 1, DEFENDER: 2 };`

   store as numbers and use this declaration in my nodejs app? Like: `player.role === roles.FORWARD ? 'Great!' : 'He cann\'t score a goal';` ?

Is there any performance reason to use second way? Are there any other reasons to use first way?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443228/enums-in-mongodb

Comment: Store it as plain text, it's more the NoSQL philosophy. Performance issues would probably be anecdotic and you would improve data decoupling from your application.